# Realize synchronous communication via two JMS queues?

Tags: jakarta-ee, queue, jms, wildfly, hornetq

There are two different JMS (HornetQ) queues, one for outgoing requests to a service and another one for incoming answers.

I want to use a single class to have simultaneous read/write access to those queues to be able to make synchronous calls to that bean.

Architecture would be:
JavaEE business application -> JavaEE "service management" facade -> JMS queues -> outside service

What would the implementation of the service management facade have to look like? I assume a combination between message driven beans and a stateful bean?

Comment: using an framework such as spring-jms?

Comment: no, I'm not since this is not a Spring project. Just JMS API on Wildfly8.